# Passing an array of Strings from Groovy to Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, groovy, quotes

I am building an array of Strings in my Groovy code and want to pass the array to a JavaScript script contained in my code.
However, Groovy doesn't put the strings in the array into quotes as Javascript expects. I'm passing the array using GStrings:

```
var strains = ${strainNames};
```

JavaScript evaluates it to this:

```
var strains = [pseudomonas_aeruginosa_D421, pseudomonas_aeruginosa_OC2E, pseudomonas_aeruginosa_EA0A, pseudomonas_aeruginosa_0812];
```

Is there a way to add quotes to each element or do I already have to add them in my Groovy code?

Answer (score 2):

You could change:

```
var strains = ${strainNames};
```

to

```
var strains = ${strainNames.inspect()};
```

Comment: That gives me the same array without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to include it as a string and transform it to an array:

```
var strains = "${strainNames}"
  .slice(1, -1)  // Remove brackets
  .split(", ");   // Split at separators
```